# Question about the function $\left\| (a_{j,1}(t),\dots,a_{j,m}(t)) \right\|:I \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My book says that the system $$ \left\{\begin{align} x_1'(t)&=f_1(t,x_1(t),x_2(t),\dots,x_m(t)) \\ x_2'(t)&=f_2(t,x_1(t),x_2(t),\dots,x_m(t)) \\ &\vdots \\ x_m'(t)&=f_m(t,x_1(t),x_2(t),\dots,x_m(t))  \end{align} \right.$$
has a unique solution if $f:I\times \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is continous and locally Lipschitz, and if we add a Cauchy condition (initial value) $x(t_0)=x_0$.

Now it proceeds to show that linear systems also satisfy the required Lipschitz condition: $$ f(t,x_2)-f(t,x_1)=A(t)x_2+b(t)-(A(t)x_1+b(t))=A(t)(x_2-x_1).$$

Here comes the part that confuses me:

> Since each $a_{i,j}(t)$ is continuous, the function $\left\| (a_{j,1}(t),\dots,a_{j,m}(t)) \right\|:I \to \mathbb{R}$ reaches its maximum $C_j$ on a compact interval $[a,b]\subseteq I$ for $j=1,\dots,m$.

So, I don't know why the elements $a_{i,j}(t)$ of $A(t)$ are continuous. Is it because the continuity of $f$ was already assumed?

And then the biggest mystery, what on Earth does the function $\left\| (a_{j,1}(t),\dots,a_{j,m}(t)) \right\|:I \to \mathbb{R}$ represent? What is the norm doing there?

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: The Lipschitz condition isn't that $f(t,x_{2})-f(t,x_{1}) = A(t)(x_{2}-x_{1})$, it's that $$\lvert f(t,x_{2})-f(t,x_{1}) \rvert \le C \lvert (x_{2}-x_{1}) \rvert$$ where $C$ is a constant. For a _system_ of equations, can you see how this relates to taking the norms of the rows of $A$?

Comment: Considering the $j$-th component: $|f_j(t,x_2) - f_j(t,x-1)| = |(a_{j,1}(t),\dots,a_{j,m}(t))\cdot (x_2-x_1)| \le C_j \left\| x_2-x_1 \right\|$. This is the proof for the Lipschitz condition. But the question isn't as much about the proof as it is about trying to understand the function that is defined above.